# I want to get all auto_incremented_id of a table in comma seperated format with one query is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql

Table structure is like given below

```
id           Name
1            Mukesh
2            Shiwam
3            deepak
4            ------
```

I want in resultant Like 1,2,3,4 it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM yTable
```

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Wth do you need this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM table
```

It's as simple as it gets. Cularis' answer specifies using the `,` separator, but it's not actually necessary, unless you want spaces between the commas:

```
32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49
```

Which you didn't specify in your OP.

Comment: thx edited, but don't know why it should put two commas in to seperate results when you specify onE.

Comment: I've edited this post like 500 times with incorrect info in each one. The one you see now is correct - I had the syntax wrong.